# Eeeek! Lazerpewpew will return!

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

I made a dumb dumb. I thought the the ME3 contest ends at midnight, EDT. But it turned out to be midnight UTC. I need to do some extra css work to get the mothership back.

yes mothership lazerpewpew will be back in the next production build, don't panic!

[image]

Comment: Do we have permission to ping you constantly until it's put back in?

Comment: I like your pre-emptive action to avoid getting lynched :)

Comment: I am hereby renouncing my membership in the [tag:jin-fanclub]

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz nooo i'll change i promise!

Comment: Something tells me you didn't REALLY want that bacon. Or else this might never have happened. Perhaps I'll go away for now. And maybe when I come back, it will be like this never happened? That would be best.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Past me, Y U DISAPPOINT? I fixed your mess, don't do this to me again.

Comment: Okay, now that that dirty business is over, next request: META NEEDS LAZERS

Comment: @Sterno Dental Plan?

Comment: Why no meta lasers?

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz Lisa needs Lasers?

Answer (score 14):

Until we get our lazers back, we are holding the site ransom for...

### ONE <s>M</s>-BEEELION DOLLARS

[image]

Yours Truly,

The Community

Comment: A meeelion is a lot of money, but I think a real number will be more effective.

Comment: I added a visual aid to properly display our demands.

Comment: I would've asked for one hundred meeelion dollars

Comment: What kind of ransom? should we make loads of minor edits rendering the homepage useless?